# org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored

Tags: java, tomcat, connector, tomcat-valve

Using Tomcat server 8.5.4 as a standalone service (tomcat8w.exe), I get the below error in 'logs/tomcat8-stderr.YYYY-MM-DD.txt' when I stop the server :

```
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.getSslSupport(NioEndpoint.java:1349)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:775)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:830)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.add(NioEndpoint.java:669)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.registerReadInterest(NioEndpoint.java:1264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1433)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My connector is the following:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keyAlias="xxx" keystoreFile="F:\Programs\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\certificate\xxx.keystore" keystorePass="xxx" maxThreads="150" port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation" scheme="https" secure="true" sslEnabledProtocols="all" sslProtocol="SSL"/>
```

Do you have any explanation on what might be wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found out that replacing 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol' with 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol' turns out to work.
I solved my problem but still, any comment / advise or solution on this is welcome.